# Scroll down to gradually hide a menu bar or view and scroll up

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I want to create a menu bar on top of a collectionview. When the user scroll down, the menu bar will gradually hide but while the user scroll up , the menu bar will appear immediately. The behavior similar to navigation bar's hidewhenswipe function. Is that any solution to create such behaviour on this menu bar? Thanks.

[screenshot][image: 1]

Answer (score 6):

1. Give your header view a height constraint if not given already. Then wired that constraint e.g.

   @IBOutlet weak var headerViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
2. Confirm your ViewController to UICollectionViewDelegate and UIScrollViewDelegate
3. set collectionView.delegate = self in ViewDidLoad()
4. UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView so you can override the delegate method of **scrollViewDidScroll** and use the following code

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 50 {// the value when you want the headerview to hide
       view.layoutIfNeeded()
       headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }, completion: nil)

   }else {
       // expand the header
       view.layoutIfNeeded()
       headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100 // Your initial height of header view
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }, completion: nil)
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: bro I think I failed, because the header view is not part of the UIcollectionview, so how to display it immediately the whole header when the user scroll up a bit from the current offset?

Comment: This is great! Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [HidingNavigationBarManager](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar) to do what you just described
and it is very easy to use. If you have a tableView in your ViewController then
it's as easy as adding these lines to your code.

```
var hidingNavBarManager: HidingNavigationBarManager?
...
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hidingNavBarManager = HidingNavigationBarManager(viewController: self, scrollView: tableView)

  }
```

Comment: but I want to hide a custom made view, not navigation bar